# How to pass Proc as block with additional arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say, I have the following code:

```
File.open("text.txt", "w") do |f|
  f << "hello"
end
```

**How do I pass the block if it is given as a Proc?**
I tried:

```
log_to_file = Proc.new { |f| f << "hello"}

File.open("text.txt", "w")(&log_to_file)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as the last argument

```rb
File.open("text.txt", "w", &log_to_file)
```